# How to end the running of python script that started SSMS?

Tags: python, cmd, ssms, os.system

I have the following code to run SSMS from `python` script (because I want it to run automatically before I get to work):

```
import os
run_line = ' '.join(['ssms.exe', '-S', server_name, '-U', user_name, '-P', my_password])
os.system('cmd /c ' + run_line)
```

Where `server_name user_name my_password` hold the arguments for the `ssms.exe` running.
It works and starts the SSMS using the user and password, but the script doesn't terminate until I close the SSMS, or shut it down manually.
How can I run the program and end the script automatically without closing the SSMS?

Comment: Take also a look at this: [How to execute a program or call a system command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/89228)

Answer (score -2):

I am not shure if this helps you but I use regulary

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

sys.exit() will stop your programm from running

Comment: It doesn't help, as the script stays in the `os.system` line, and doesn't run anything after it.